# Ability to Review Closed Questions

Tags: feature-request

I just reviewed a First Posted question that looked like one that might have been recently posted and closed.

I tried going back through the currently listed questions, for the past 6 weeks, but I couldn't find anything.

Is there an easy way to view closed questions to see if a newly posted question is a rehash of a previously closed question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/7874/16) is the one you're referring to that you saw in the review queue.

And it appears that [this older question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/3326/16) is a fairly close duplicate of the one you saw.  However, the older question is several months older and likely wouldn't have been the one you were thinking of.

Using a combination of terms and even searching through deleted questions,<sup>1</sup> I wasn't able to find any other suitable matches.

But with that said, let's address your question:

> Is there an easy way to view closed questions to see if a newly posted question is a rehash of a previously closed question?

The short answer is yes, there are some easy ways.  And the [search help](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/searching) gives you some tips on conditionals that you can apply to the search terms.

In this case, I would have used "is:question closed:yes" in order to narrow the search and then sorted that view by newest posts.

An example of what I might have searched on [can be found here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=roller%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ayes).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Apparently that diamond thingy after my name can come in handy...*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that was the question I was referring to & thanks for the search tips.